# How to add a counting column for specific values (as sub-select)

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I have a query that I want to add a colum to. It should contain the amount of how many times a value of a specific column appears in that table.

My current attempt

```
SELECT cleaning.*,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM cleaning
        WHERE column_b = cleaning.column_b)
        AS multicleanamount
    FROM cleaning
```

is counting **every single row** as it is just comparing a column with same column - I understand the reason.
So the current (wrong) result is

| column_a | column_b | multicleanamount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 300 | 7 |
| 13 | 321 | 7 |
| 14 | 300 | 7 |
| 15 | 330 | 7 |
| 16 | 330 | 7 |
| 17 | 351 | 7 |
| 18 | 330 | 7 |

What I am missing now is how do I tell the sub-Select to compare with the current value of `cleaning.column_b` from the very first line? (which is in the `cleaning.*`)

2bh it was pretty easy in my head at first and it also would be if I'd compare to a static value like `'300'` but that table has 74 K entries. This has to be dynamic.

**My desired output is**

| column_a | column_b | multicleanamount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 300 | 2 |
| 13 | 321 | 1 |
| 14 | 300 | 2 |
| 15 | 330 | 3 |
| 16 | 330 | 3 |
| 17 | 351 | 1 |
| 18 | 330 | 3 |

I hope that is understandable. If not please tell me and I will try to specify even more.

Comment: Thank you for reformatting @Barmar

Comment: Was it just because of the missing empty lines before and after the tables? That should be implemented in the preview aswell then. It was displayed correctly before I posted the question.

Comment: I think you found a *feature*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use table aliases so you can distinguish the `cleaning` table in the subquery from the table in the main query. In your query, `WHERE column_b = cleaning.column_b` is comparing the column with itself, so the condition is always true and you're counting all the rows.

```
SELECT c1.*,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM cleaning AS c2
        WHERE c1.column_b = c2.column_b)
        AS multicleanamount
FROM cleaning AS c1
```

It may also be better to write this as a `JOIN` instead of correlated subquery:

```
SELECT c1.*, c2.multicleanamount
FROM cleaning AS c1
JOIN (
    SELECT column_b, COUNT(*) AS multicleanamount
    FROM cleaning
    GROUP BY column_b
) AS c2 ON c1.column_b = c2.column_b
```

Comment: Can I also add a filter at the end so I can check for rows that are ``>1`` ? It seems I can't simply add ``WHERE multicleanamount >1`` as it's not a valid reference in that case.

Comment: You can use `HAVING multicleanamount > 1` in the subquery or `WHERE multicleanamount > 1` in the main query.

Comment: My initial attempt before that comment was ``WHERE [...] AND multicleanamount > 1`` in the main query. But the result just shows that ``multicleanamount`` is an unknown column. ``HAVING multicleanamount > 1`` in subquery leads to ``Reference "multicleanamount" not supported``.

Comment: I was talking about the second version with the `JOIN`.

Comment: See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2dd242/1

Comment: OKay. Works great with the JOIN. Thanks.